# Calling functions defined in a class using AsyncTask android

Tags: android

My code goes as below :-

```
public class Activity2 extends ListActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  .
  .
  readDatafromfile();
}

public void readDatafromfile(){
..
}
```

Now I want to do this reading asynchronously. I have created yet another class for this but I am not able to call the method ( `readDatafromfile()` ).

Please help.

Comment: Did you move `readDataFromFile()` to the `AsyncTask` class? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Can you not just call 'Activity2.redDatafromFile()' from your other class?

Comment: @Smittey then the readDatafromfile function needs to be declared as static.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options to do that:

**Define readDatafromfile() as static in your Activity class.**

```
public class Activity2 extends ListActivity
{    public void readDatafromfile(){}    }
```

**Define readDatafromfile() in your AsyncTask and pass your Activity as context.**

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask < Void , Void , Void >
{   
    Context ctx;
    public MyAsync ( Context ctx ){ this.ctx = ctx; }
    public void readDatafromfile(){}
}
```

**Create and interface IOOperation that contains readDatafromfile() , let your activity implement that, and pass it to your AsyncTask.**

interface

```
public interface IOOperation
{    public void readDatafromfile();    }
```

activity

```
public class Activity2 extends ListActivity implements IOOperation
{   
    @override 
    public void readDatafromfile(){}    }
```

asynctask

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask < Void , Void , Void >
{   
    IOOperation reader;
    public MyAsync ( IOOperation reader){ this.reader= reader; }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args)
    {    reader.readDatafromfile();    }
}
```